# How do I get all available locales in spanish using Java?

Tags: java, locale

I do know how to get a list of all available locales in english using the method getAvailableLocales() of the class SimpleDateFormat in Java. But I want to get it in spanish.

Comment: The list is universal, there is no translated version.  Make note that the languages are all abbreviations of the way they are natively known, not how English speakers know them.  Example:  German is "de"  and Spanish is "es".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, but it seems that you want to get all locales in Spanish language. It can be made as:

```
    Locale.setDefault(new Locale("ES"));
    Locale[] locales = SimpleDateFormat.getAvailableLocales();
    for(Locale l : locales) {
        System.out.println(l.getDisplayName());
    }
```

At first you have to set default locale to Spanish and get all locales.

Comment: interesting - does that change the list?

Comment: What do you mean? Could you explain better your question?

Comment: sorry, what i mean is: does that change the list of locales, or does it just modify getDisplayName so that the returned value is in the default locale?

Comment: Yes, I checked that solution. It doesn't modify locales, it just changes displayed names like: `getDisplayCountry(), getDisplayName(), getDisplayLanguage()` (getDisplayX pattern). You can check documentation for [getDisplayCountry()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayCountry()) method. It tells that `Returns a name for the locale's country that is appropriate for display to the user. If possible, the name returned will be localized for the default locale. `

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Locale loc = new Locale(language, country);
```

and

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(loc);
```

I hope help you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, according to bontade and if you want to filter spanish speaking countries you can add l.getLanguage().equals("es") condition to do that